# jQuery UI Datepicker, How can I make the text box editable by keyboard using the 'oo' dateformat?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, formatting, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the date picker with the leading zero day of the year format.
My users also want to be able to enter the day of the year ('012', '034', '356') using their keyboard. Using the datepicker dateformat code, `'oo'`, the text is not able to be entered by keyboard... but you can delete it using the delete and backspace keys.

Here is my code:

> $( '#dateFieldID' ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'oo' });

It formats the date field as expected when choosing a date from the animated box but does not allow text entry from the keyboard.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So messing around with this issue I found that I can enter characters using the keyboard, 'o' and 'o'.. that is it. weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the datepicker default is to constrain the input to what is allowed by the implemented datepicker format. In the case of my question, the only allowable character input was 'oo'.  (Those are two lowercase letter 'O'.)

See: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-constrainInput

While that helped the system identify the particular Julian style date format it constrained the input allowed, not good.

By changing the value of the constrainInput option to 'false' we can then add our numbers and put a validation on it if needed.

Here is the code with option set to allow for numbers:

`$( '#dateFieldID' ).datepicker({ constrainInput: false, dateFormat: 'oo' });`